# Running IDL routines from Java

Tags: java, terminal, idl-programming-language

I want to run an IDL routine ([this, specifically](https://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/robust/robust_sigma.pro)) from some Java code I'm writing. If possible, I'd like to be able to pass arrays and scalars to and from both languages. Is this at all possible?

Comment: The way SO works is that you show us the code you are using and describe what is not working as well as how it needs to work.

Comment: I'm sitting next to the guy that wrote it and we both agree that this question is not a good example of how to use SO.

Comment: Also, the answer to the question that you are asking at the moment is "yes, it is possible". Please be explicit rather than implicit, even if you are just asking us to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDL Online Help has sections on this ("About The IDL Connector Object" and "Data Manipulation with a Java Connector Object") that should help you to know that yes, you can do this! These are available on the Harris website:

https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/AboutTheIDLConnectorObject.html
https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/DataManipulationwithaJavaConnectorObject.html

If you have access to IDL Online Help, you can find them in these Contents sections:

> Bridges > Java and COM - Connector Objects > About The IDL Connector
>   Object
>  Bridges > Java and COM - Connector Objects > Data
>   Manipulation with a Java Connector Object

I notice that the Java method "getIDLVariable" (which retrieves the named variable from the IDL process associated with the underlying IDL object) has a Note: "This method is disabled for applications running in the IDL Virtual Machine." So, you will need access to a fully licensed copy of IDL to do this.